# Search in multi fields in databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, search

I have three fields namely (city - name - date) and I want to enable user to search using one field or two fields or three fields together . Please, I need a best way to do that ....I am using php codeigniter and mysql for database.

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: I need logic and best way to do that and any helpful articls about search in databsea

Answer (score 2):

Ex:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1=1 ';
if(isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']) )
    $sql .= ' AND city LIKE "%'.$_POST['city'].'%" ';
```

And one more for each column or field to search.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL string should be something along this:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE city LIKE '%".$city."%' OR name LIKE '%".$name."%' OR date LIKE '%".$date."%'
```

The query above will return a row if one of the criteria are true. F.x. if i type "York" in city and "Alex" in name, it will return every row where "York" is in the city cell (It will return "New York" because York is in that city name). But it will also return every row with Alex in the name.

If you want it to only return rows where all the criteria are true you need to put "AND" instead of "OR".